# Get user access token from user_id (app already authorized)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I have a poll app running on facebook (each user gets a vote each day). Until now I didn't store on my database the user access token. This is now updated and I'm keeping the access token by this time. Each time a user votes I save his access token.

My problem is how to get the user's access token from previous votes, is this possible considering that they have authorized my app? Is there a method for this? I have the users id.

(the only reason for needing this is to get the "is_verified" property from FB graph API)

Thanks for your help,

Hugo

Comment: i dont think you can get access token of users which had previously voted on your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get user `access_token` without authenticate him.

You can however send your users app to user request engaging user to visit your application so you'll be able to store user's `access_token`.

Beware that `access_token` may expire and [`offline_access` permission is deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) (and will be removed soon), you can extend tokens up to 60 days (extending will only works for users who re-authenticated, not already authenticated)...

Comment: Thanks Juicy, can you explain this sentence please: "You can however send your users app to user request engaging user to visit your application so you'll be able to store user's access_token." How can I engage them to visit my app?

Comment: @Hugo, you can use send [requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) (see App to User Requests section) from your application via Graph API for users you have no `access_token`. Once user accept request he will visit your application and you'll be able to get fresh `access_token` and retrieve needed info.